# web service which returns picture and text

Tags: java, android, web-services

My Android app needs to make contact with a web service(which does not exist yet) which should return a jpg image and some text to go along with it... is that even possible ? How is that implemented? Now, I have made contact with a web service to get back a Json file full of text... but never an jpg...

Here is what i have coded so far in my Android app:

```
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
              conn.setDoOutput(true); 
              OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
              wr.write( data ); 
              wr.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Android app needs to make contact with a web service(which does not exist yet) which should return a jpg image and some text to go along with it... is that even possible ?

The conventional approach for this is for the Web service to return JSON/XML/whatever that contains a URL to download the image.

For example, [the StackExchange API for questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) returns links to the URLs for the profile images for the people asking questions and supplying answers.

> How is that implemented?

On the server side, that would depend upon the implementation of the server. Please feel free to ask a separate, appropriately-tagged StackOverflow question to get assistance with your Web service implementation.

On the client side, you perform one HTTP request to get the basic data, and separate HTTP request(s) to get the image(s).

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso), for example, uses Retrofit to retrieve StackOverflow questions with the [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) tag and Picasso to download the profile images for the people asking the questions.

Comment: so I guess that was the answer to my question, it must be done in 2 different http requests.. right

Comment: @user3134565: You are welcome to experiment with binary Web service protocols (e.g., Protocol Buffers) to send text and images down in a single response. That tends to be a bit more difficult to implement, and it may not be any more efficient overall (e.g., Web server cannot use caching on the images).